# Control-M: Order date (prerequisite), two jobs with different load dates

Tags: scheduling, prerequisites, control-m

I have two jobs with different load dates (not same day):

- JobA: runs at the end of month (may be 28th, 29 th, 30th).
- JobB: runs at the beginning of the month (may be 1st, 2nd).

I want to make JobA as prerequisite of JobB.

How can I proceed, in control M, since the two jobs are not in the same load date and they don't have specific date to run.

Answer (score 1):

This situation can be easily handled with the use of STAT conditions.
Normally conditions are order date dependent, but if you change the condition from ODAT to STAT then the order date is not taken into consideration.
Ensure that you are removing the STAT condition on JobB after completion (on failure or success) to avoid next months JobB kicking off prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

Re-elaborating Jasper answer, my suggestion is: on JobA, in the "On Do Actions" add the following action with attention to "Date" parameter which must be "No Date":

[image]

On JobB prerequisites add the condition. Again, with "No Date":
[image]

In JobB, in "On Do Actions" add the following action, to manage the condition:
[image]